# Elements not coming in line

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var unitBtn = document.getElementById("dropdown-btn"); // the button which when clicked, a menu will appear
var dropDownContent = document.getElementById("dropdown-content"); // the content to be displayed when the button above is clicked

// the unitBtn is clicked
unitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // if the visibility is hidden
    if(dropDownContent.style.visibility == "hidden") {
        dropDownContent.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else { // if it is not...
        dropDownContent.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
});

// the options
var kmBtn = document.getElementById("km");
var metreBtn = document.getElementById("m");
var celsiusBtn = document.getElementById("celsius");
var fahrenheitBtn = document.getElementById("fahrenheit");

kmBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    unitBtn.value = kmBtn.value;
    dropDownContent.style.visibility = "hidden";
});

metreBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    unitBtn.value = metreBtn.value;
    dropDownContent.style.visibility = "hidden";
});

celsiusBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    unitBtn.value = celsiusBtn.value;
    dropDownContent.style.visibility = "hidden";
});

fahrenheitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    unitBtn.value = fahrenheitBtn.value;
    dropDownContent.style.visibility = "hidden";
});


// claculate button being clci
var calculateBtn = document.getElementById("calculate-btn");
calculateBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // hello
});
```

```css
/* Background-color, title, intro (the general stuff) */
body {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 255, 0.4);
}

#title {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
    font-size: 35px;
}

#intro-para {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

/* Now for the options */
#dropdown-content {
    margin-left: 169px;
}

/* in line */
#dropdown-stuff {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Conversion</title>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <style>
            #dropdown-content {
                visibility: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Title and Intro -->
        <h1 id="title">Conversion</h1>
        <p id="intro-para">Don't know how to convert? Too lazy to pop up a calculator? Don't worry, We have you covered!</p>

        <!-- Calculation buttons, inputs and options -->
        <!-- Value 1 -->
        <input type="text" id="value1-btn" placeholder="Value 1">

        <!-- Options so that we know the unit which the user wants to convert -->
        <div id="dropdown-stuff">
        <input type="button" value="Select unit" id="dropdown-btn">
        <div id="dropdown-content">
            <input type="button" value="kilometre" id="km">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="metre" id="m">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="celsius" id="celsius">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="fahrenheit" id="fahrenheit">
        </div>

        <p id="to">to</p>

        <!-- Calculate button -->
        <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate-btn">
        </div>

        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="js.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the HTML code above, in the div with an id of "dropdown-stuff" I have put in a p element `<p id="to">to</p>` and a button - `<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate-btn">`. However, they are not coming in line with my input and "select unit" button even though they are in `#dropdown-stuff`

I have put the CSS code for `#dropdown-stuff` as below -

```
#dropdown-stuff {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: inline;
}
```

Why is my p element and calculate button not coming in line with dropdown button and Value 1 text input? How to fix this?

EDIT: I changed the `display` to `flex`. Now they are coming in a row, however the calculate (#calculate-btn) and dropdown (#dropdown-btn) buttons are HUGE blocks and the options (#dropdown-content) which appear when the dropdown button  (#dropdown-btn) is clicked, the options appear to the right of the button and not to the bottom of the button.

Comment: Welcome `flex-direction:` work with display flex not inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex-direction: row` will only have an effect for `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`.

So this might give you what you're looking for:

```css
#dropdown-stuff {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Hello, @Eddie Reeder, now the buttons are coming as HUGE blocks and when I click on "Select Unit" (#dropdown-btn) the options are coming to the right of it, not below the button

Comment: They are coming in the same "row" (thanks for the help) but the above problem persists

Comment: You needed to enclose your dropdown input and content in their own containing div. I've fixed your problem [here](https://codepen.io/eddireeder/pen/yLJBvvr). :)

Comment: Thanks, @Eddie Reeder.